# Unfixed div overlapping fixed div on bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have my layout page divided into two columns using bootstrap 3 with something similar to this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 info">
    <!--some Markup -->
  </div>

  <div class = "col-md-8 tasks-column">
    <!--some Markup -->
  </div> 
</div>
```

I want the div with class "info" to stay fixed on the top left side when scrolling the page. When I try the bootstrap "affix" class the content in "info" effectively gets fixed but the "tasks-column" suddenly moves all the way to the left completely covering it. 
I have also tried the plain css position:fixed; on "info" but it does not do anything. 
The content in info is NOT a navigation panel.
Thank you guys.

Edit: the content in info is dynamic (it varies depending on the user input).

Comment: Add margin-left to .tasks-column, equals to .info width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to offset the tasks-column. Try this.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 info">
       <!--some Markup -->
   </div>

   <div class = "col-md-8 col-md-offset-4 tasks-column">
       <!--some Markup -->
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are fixing the content that pushes "tasks-column" to the right.
The simple way to do what you want is just to move "info" inside col-md-4, like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="info">
            <!--some fixed Markup -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 tasks-column">
         <!--some Markup -->
    </div> 
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, so it partially worked. The tasks column does not overlap, but now the content on "info" now extends all the way to the right, not respecting the boundaries of the parent.